# simply trying to use a <span> character to call a javascript function to close dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, html, css, drop-down-menu

So I'm a total beginner in javascript and I'm just getting back into the swing of html/css, so I'm all around rusty. W3 is basically my go to and has got me started, but I've scoured google and stack overflow for a simple solution I can understand and I've come up with nothing. Can anyone explain to me what's going wrong with a simple function?

I have a drop down menu that appears from an onclick function attached to a div which basically looks like

```
function openMobileMenu(){
   document.getElementById("mobilelinkmenu").style.display="block";
}
```

and that works fine, my menu pops up just fine.

When it's time to close that menu I have a `<span onclick="closeMobileMenu()"> + </span>` inside of that div to act as a closing button, and the code looks like this

```
function closeMobileMenu(){
    document.getElementById("mobilelinkmenu").style.display="hidden";
}
```

I'm sure I'm making some rookie mistake and nothing can be that simple, but can anyone point to the source of my mistake? I just want to finish this dang menu and move on. Is it because my exit function span is inside of the opening function div and when I'm clicking on the exiting span, it's really just clicking on the opening div?

Here's the code

```
 <div id="navbar" class="mobilemenustyle" onclick="openMobileMenu()">
      <img src="images/navicon.jpg" alt="nav" width=10%>
     <span onclick="closeMobileMenu()">Nav Menu</span> <span class="exit" onclick="closeMobileMenu()" > + </span>
      </div>   


          <!--opened nav menu--> <div id="mobilelinkmenu" class="mobilemenustyle"> <ul> <li><a href="index.html">You Are Here</a></li> <li><a href="photography.html">Photography</a></li> <li><a href="music.html">Musicality</a></li> <li><a href="djlife.html">DJ Life</a></li> <li><a href="reachout.html">More Me</a></li> </ul> </div>

      <script>
          function openMobileMenu(){
         document.getElementById("mobilelinkmenu").style.display="block";
        document.getElementById("navbar").style.boxShadow="none";
        document.getElementById("mobilelinkmenu").style.boxShadow="0px 10px 15px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.3)";
              var exit = document.getElementsByClassName("exit"), i=exit.length;
              while(i--){exit[i].style.transform="rotate(45deg)";
                        }
               var exit = document.getElementsByClassName("exit"), i=exit.length;
              while(i--){exit[i].style.transition=".5s ease-in-out";
                        }

          }

          function closeMobileMenu(){
           document.getElementById("mobilelinkmenu").style.display="hidden";

          }
      </script>
```

Comment: Please post all of the relevant code.

Comment: Let me know if you need the CSS, and also, if anyone knows how to combine multiple CSS edits on the same element into one document.getelementbyid line, please let me know. Like I said, I'm basically in the dark here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call [`event.stopPropagation()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation) to stop the click event from bubbling to the `div` with the `id` of "navbar" and opening the menu. When you click on the `span` inside the `div`, the `onclick` event handler for it is called (to close the menu), but the event will bubble up to its parent `div` and call its `onclick` event handler (opening the menu again). Using `event.stopPropagation()` will prevent the `event` from bubbling up the DOM tree.

You also need to change

```
document.getElementById("mobilelinkmenu").style.display="hidden";
```

To

```
document.getElementById("mobilelinkmenu").style.display="none";
```

`"hidden"` is an invalid property value for the `display` CSS property (it can be used with the `visibility` property).

```css
.rotated{
  display: inline-block;
   -ms-transform: rotate(45deg); 
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}
.rotated:hover{
  color: red;
}
.exit{
    -webkit-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  transition: .5s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
 <div id="navbar" class="mobilemenustyle" onclick="openMobileMenu()">
      <img src="images/navicon.jpg" alt="nav" width=10%>
     <span onclick="closeMobileMenu(event)">Nav Menu</span> <span class="exit" onclick="closeMobileMenu(event)" > + </span>
      </div>   


          <!--opened nav menu--> <div id="mobilelinkmenu" style="display: none;" class="mobilemenustyle"> <ul> <li><a href="index.html">You Are Here</a></li> <li><a href="photography.html">Photography</a></li> <li><a href="music.html">Musicality</a></li> <li><a href="djlife.html">DJ Life</a></li> <li><a href="reachout.html">More Me</a></li> </ul> </div>

      <script>
          function openMobileMenu(){
         document.getElementById("mobilelinkmenu").style.display="block";
        document.getElementById("navbar").style.boxShadow="none";
        document.getElementById("mobilelinkmenu").style.boxShadow="0px 10px 15px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.3)";
              var exit = document.getElementsByClassName("exit"), i=exit.length;
              while(i--){
              exit[i].classList.add("rotated");
              }

          }

          function closeMobileMenu(e){
          e.stopPropagation(); 
         document.getElementById("mobilelinkmenu").style.display="none";
         var exit = document.getElementsByClassName("exit"), i=exit.length;
              while(i--){
              exit[i].classList.remove("rotated");
              }
          }
      </script>
```

Comment: That seems to have done the trick! Any chance you would know how to keep my " + " rotating when I open and close the menu? It rotates from + to x when I click to open the menu, but that's the only time.

Comment: You're awesome. It works perfectly. So basically you're just adding/removing the CSS transformations?

Comment: @AlPal I am adding and removing a class with the CSS transformations.